The infimum of Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz.
Proposition. Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $\{ f_i : i \in I \}$ be a family of Lipschitz functions defined on $X$, where each $f_i: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz with constant $L_i$, i.e., for all $x, y \in X$,
$$
|f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq L_i \cdot d(x, y).
$$
Define $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x) = \inf_{i \in I} f_i(x).
$$
Then $f$ is also a Lipschitz function on $X$ with Lipschitz constant
$$
L = \sup_{i \in I} L_i.
$$
My proof:
Let $x, y \in X$. We want to show that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L \cdot d(x, y).
$$
By definition of $f$, we have:
$$
f(x) = \inf_{i \in I} f_i(x) \quad \text{and} \quad f(y) = \inf_{i \in I} f_i(y).
$$
Using the properties of the infimum, we obtain:
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = \left| \inf_{i \in I} f_i(x) - \inf_{i \in I} f_i(y) \right| \leq \sup_{i \in I} |f_i(x) - f_i(y)|.
$$
For any $i \in I$, since $f_i$ is Lipschitz with constant $L_i$, we have:
$$
|f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq L_i \cdot d(x, y).
$$
Thus, we can write:
$$
\sup_{i \in I} |f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq \sup_{i \in I} L_i \cdot d(x, y) = L \cdot d(x, y),
$$
where $L = \sup_{i \in I} L_i$. Therefore, we conclude that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L \cdot d(x, y).
$$
This shows that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $L$, completing the proof.
I would like to know if my demonstration is correct. Thanks for the help!

You should assume that the sequence $(L_i)$ is bounded.

The first problem you need to address is that the infimum of functions need not exist for a family of Lipschitz functions. Consider $f_a(x) = ax$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ we have that $f(x) = \inf_{a\in\mathbb{R}} f_a(x) = -\infty$.

Not quite, you forgot about $x=0$. A better example is the sequence of constant functions $f_n(x)=-n$, $n\in \mathbb N$.

@MoisheKohan excellent catch! Updated.

The problem I see is that $L$ is not well defined (or, in any case, infinite), since if for some $f_i, i\in I$, its associated Lipschitz constant is $L_i \neq 0$, then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ we have that $\alpha f_i$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $|\alpha|L_i$. Hence, the set $\{L_i:i \in I\}$ is not bounded and has no supremum.

Is there any way to fix this?

I would say that the only way to "fix" this is to restrict the set of functions you're considering for your proposition, since as mentioned in another response here, not even the "infimum function" is well defined in your proposition, so it cannot be true in general.
However, I think that if you restrict it to any set of Lipschitz functions that are lower-bounded (as the set, i.e., that your "infimum function" can be well defined) and that the set of their Lipschitz constants is upper-bounded, the proposition may be correct, and it's still relatively general.
